# String handling in Java using substring()

Tags: java, string

In this program I have currently asked the user to enter date in the format mm/dd/yyyy, but I want to be able to work with the entry in the format m/d/yyyy, mm/d/yyyy, or m/dd/yyyy. How can I do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BirthdayReminder
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // declare variables here

       String[] names = new String[10];
       String inputName;
       String birthday;
       int[] month = new int[10];
       int[] day = new int[10];
       int[] year = new int[10];
       int count = 0;
       final int MAX = 10;
       final String QUIT = "ZZZ";
       String inputMonth;
       String inputDay;
       String inputYear;

       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the name of a friend >> ");
       inputName = input.nextLine();
       System.out.print("Enter friend's birthday in format mm/dd/yyyy >> ");
       birthday = input.nextLine();

      // allow user to enter up to 10 friends, first their name, then their birthday with slashes
      // between the month, day, and year, or until they enter ZZZ as a name

       while(inputName.compareTo(QUIT) != 0)
       {
           names[count] = inputName;

           inputMonth = birthday.substring(0, 2);
           inputDay = birthday.substring(3, 5);
           inputYear = birthday.substring(6, 10);

           int intMonth = Integer.parseInt(inputMonth);
           int intDay = Integer.parseInt(inputDay);
           int intYear = Integer.parseInt(inputYear);

           month[count] = intMonth;
           day[count] = intDay;
           year[count] = intYear;

           ++count;

           if(count == MAX)
               inputName = QUIT;
           else
           {
               System.out.print("Enter next friend's name or " + QUIT + " to quit >> ");
               inputName = input.nextLine();

               if(inputName.compareTo(QUIT) !=0)
               {
                   System.out.print("Enter friend's birthday in format mm/dd/yyyy >> ");
                   birthday = input.nextLine();
               }
           }
       }

       System.out.println("You have entered " + count + " names.");
       System.out.println("The names you entered are ");
       for(int y = 0; y < count; ++y)
       {
           System.out.print(names[y] + " ");
       }
      // prompt user to enter names of their friends and display the applicable birthday, until the
      // user enters ZZZ as a name

       if(count != 0)
       {
           System.out.println("\nEnter friend's name to see his/her birthday or ZZZ to quit >> ");
           String friendName = input.nextLine();

           for(int i = 0; i < friendName.length() && friendName.compareTo(QUIT) != 0; i++)
           {
               if(friendName.compareTo(names[i]) == 0)
               {
                   System.out.println("The birthday is " + month[i] + "/" + day[i] + "/" + year[i]);
               }

               else
               {
                   System.out.println("This name has not been previously entered.");
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I've been trying to do something like this

```
int x = 0;
while(x < birthday.length())
{
   if(birthday.charAt(x) == '/')
   {
      inputMonth = birthday.substring(0, x);
      inputDay = birthday.susbtring(x + 1, something);
      inputYear = birthday.substring(x + something, birthday.length());
   }
   ++x;
}
```

but I'm not sure how to get this to work because the user entry will contain two slashes instead of one, so there will be two x's.

P.S. I have just learned basic java programming yet.

Comment: Kindly use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Curious, since you already have the User enter the birthday in the format you displayed within the prompt as a string why not just have a String Array for the supplied birthdays. Why convert it back and forth from string to integer all the time. What I'm trying to say is: Since the User is entering the birth date as `12/16/2017` why dissect the hell out of it. It's just making way more work out of it than there needs to be for the simple sake of displaying someone's birthday.

Comment: right, I didn't think of it...I was going to store the months in the month array, days in the day array, etc...but you're right, I can simply store each date in a String array. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @vinS `SimpleDateFormat` has been outmoded for years, supplanted by the java.time classes. Specifically `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a school question to demonstrate you can use substring rather than using SimpleDateFormat.

The simplest approach is do avoid the loop and just use String.indexOf(char, firstIndex) twice to get hold of the first and second slash indexes...

```
int slash1 = birthday.indexOf('/', 0);
int slash2 = birthday.indexOf('/', slash1 + 1);

String inputMonth = birthday.substring(0, slash1);
String inputDay = birthday.substring(slash1 + 1, slash2);
String inputYear = birthday.substring(slash2 + 1, birthday.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:

```
String []myFormat = {"m/d/yyyy" , "mm/d/yyyy" , "m/dd/yyyy"};
    birthday = input.nextLine();
    for(int i=0 ; i < myFormat.length ; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat datetimeFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat[i]);
            Date date =  datetimeFormatter1.parse(birthday);
            System.out.println(date.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).